# Use 3G connection on my Android in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, tethering, internet, 3g

I would like to use the 3G connection on my android with my Ubuntu. Is there any method to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate, could have a helpful answer for you: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/non-root-tethering-app-with-ubuntu-client-for-moto-droid-on-verizon

Comment: Over USB? Over wifi? Is your phone rooted? Have you looked at the multitude of other questions in the [tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tethering) and [wifi-tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi-tethering) tags and tried the solutions there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Easy Tether](http://www.mobile-stream.com/easytether/android.html) from Mobile Stream should work. It's a way to share your internet connection with another device via USB. Get the [Lite version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mstream.easytether_beta&hl=en) (does not support https, or tethering to gaming consoles) or the [Full version](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mstream.easytether_polyclef&hl=en).

> Supports Windows 7/Vista/XP (32-bit and 64-bit), Mac OS X
>   10.7/10.6/10.5/10.4, Ubuntu 10.4+ and Fedora 13+

Full version supports the following:

> Tether PS3, Wii, XBox via PC Internet Connection Sharing, you need a
>   computer for game console tethering.